# unknown argument: '-stdc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future] during build in XCODE 5.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, ios6, xcode5

I get this error when I build a project in XCODE 5.1. I followed [Link](https://langui.sh/2014/03/10/wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future-is-a-harsh-mistress/) and downloaded New command line tools from Apple.But facing same issue. Please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have 3 steps u should do to fix it:
- Remove -stdc++ in Other Linker Flags
- Add -lstdc++ into Other Linker Flags
- Add libstdc++6.09.dylib into Link binary with Libraries.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this as it's happening because of `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) :`
https://langui.sh/2014/03/10/wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future-is-a-harsh-mistress/